# Change an icon in Blazorise Treeview

Tags: blazor, blazorise

I am using Blazorise Treeview and do not find how to change default icons for opening and closing a node. The component strongly depends on fa-plus-square and fa-minus-square and I do not see how to customise it.
I can find something helpful in the official documentation : [Blazorise Treeview Documentation](https://blazorise.com/docs/extensions/treeview).
 This problem is mentioned in an issue https://github.com/Megabit/Blazorise/issues/994 not sure if there is a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I think the only solution is to override the following style

```
.fa-plus-square:before {
    content: "\f0fe" !important; // Replace the content by another icon from font awesome
}
```

But be careful, some icons need a specific font-weight. So for example to replace by a cross, I need:

```
.far.fa-plus-square {
    font-weight: 900 !important;
}
.fa-plus-square:before {
    content: "\f00d" !important;
}
```

You may need some more specific CSS selector in order to override the included style of the library, but it is definitely the way to achieve it - before github issue being resolved.

EDIT: just one info in addition, this modification will override the style of the icon itself, but you may need them somewhere else in your project, so I recommend you to encapsulate the whole Treeview component inside a dedicated div with a class, and to ajust the CSS selectors that I wrote to include the new class. (`.far.fa-plus-square` become `.my-tree-view-container .far.fa-plus-square`)

Comment: It's working. Thanks. Override the cases in the app.css file (It won't work in the code behind because of Blazor CSS isolation) and encapsulating in my div is a good advice.
I hope the component to offer this customization in the future, this approach is a little bit hacky.
Thanks again @Dylan Barquilla

Comment: @IvoAtanasov FYI, I just checked the Blazored project (in order to see if I could easily do this modification) and it is not as simple as I thought :/ But maybe someone with more time and talent will be able to achieve this change :D

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Blazorise version 1.1.0 the following parameters have been added to the `TreeView` component for customizing icons:

| Name | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `CollapseIconName` | Defines the name of the treenode collapse icon. |
| `CollapseIconSize` | Defines the size of the treenode collapse icon. |
| `CollapseIconStyle` | Defines the style of the treenode collapse icon. |
| `ExpandIconName` | Defines the name of the treenode expand icon. |
| `ExpandIconSize` | Defines the size of the treenode expand icon. |
| `ExpandIconStyle` | Defines the style of the treenode expand icon. |

[TreeView documentation](https://blazorise.com/docs/extensions/treeview)